# ImportError : in django in sphinx-python

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx

I am importing my `settings.py` in `conf.py` of sphinx.

```
import settings
from django.core.management import setup_environ
setup_environ(settings)
```

but i got this error :

```
Exception occurred:
  File "/home/imps/workspace/myproj/myproj/document/source/conf.py", line 20, in <module>
    import settings
ImportError: No module named settings
```

i try also to add the directory of my project:

```
from myproj import settings
from django.core.management import setup_environ
setup_environ(settings)
```

but i got this:

```
Exception occurred:
  File "/home/imps/workspace/myproj/myproj/document/source/conf.py", line 20, in <module>
    from myproj import settings
ImportError: No module named myproj
```

do anyone have an idea about my case?

does the sphinx is sensitive about the directory of the project to be documented?
my directory path of my project is :

```
/home/imps/workspace/myproj/myproj
```

and i put the sphinx in:

```
/home/imps/workspace/myproj/myproj/document
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it fixed by adding this to `conf.py`:

```
sys.path.append('/home/imps/workspace/myproj/myproj')
import settings
from django.core.management import setup_environ
setup_environ(settings)
```

Now I can run `make html` succesfully.

Comment: This is very very hardcoded, but it works :-) A more robust solution would be to have a `setup.py` and to use a virtualenv, especially if you later want to use readthedocs.org. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13442521/27401 for a hint.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is there an `__init__.py` in `/home/imps/workspace/myproj/myproj`?
2. How do you start your program?

   `python manage.py runserver`?

   Visit the 127.0.0.1:8000，You can see the website.
3. If you want to run the the following script: `python conf.py`, you need set your project path in your python path.You can simply add a line to the head of conf.py:

   `os.sys.path.append('/home/imps/workspace/myproj/myproj')`