# ImportError: No module named for my code on Readthedocs

Tags: django, python-sphinx, importerror, read-the-docs

I am trying to link my Sphinx documentation with *ReadtheDocs*. I can build the documentation locally but when I try to have *ReadtheDocs* automatically generate the documentation I get the following error:

Sphinx Standard Error

```
Making output directory...

Exception occurred:
  File "/var/build/user_builds/mousedb/checkouts/latest/Docs/source/conf.py", line 25, in <module>
    from mousedb import settings
ImportError: No module named mousedb
The full traceback has been saved in /tmp/sphinx-err-n_8fkR.log, if you want to report the issue to the developers.
Please also report this if it was a user error, so that a better error message can be provided next time.
Either send bugs to the mailing list at <http://groups.google.com/group/sphinx-dev/>,
or report them in the tracker at <http://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/issues/>. Thanks!
```

My project name is mousedb. I don't understand why I get this import error in the auto-build but not locally.

**Update**

Based on the comments I think that this is an issue for importing my settings file into a sibling `Docs` directory. Rather than doing an absolute import (as I had been doing) I should be doing a relative import based on the location of `settings.py` and `conf.py`.

I want to import my settings file into my `conf.py` with the following directory structure:

```
-mousedb
--settings.py
-Docs
--source
---conf.py
--build
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `Use virtualenv` checkbox in rtd settings?
    Install your project inside a virtualenv using setup.py install

Comment: i tried that, same error.  Is it possible that i need to use a relative path in my sys.path.append rather than an absolute path (as is the case for my local installation)

Comment: Your local absolute path is almost guaranteed not to exist on readthedocs' server :-)

Comment: I had a similar issue, I solved it by adding relative paths in the docs/conf.py as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65530232/5629527

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You originally talked about a "local absolute path to my code" and now about setting up relative paths to your code. This probably means you're not using a `setup.py` file and also not a virtualenv.

In the same directory as `Docs/` and `mousedb/`, add a `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='mousedb',
      version='0.1',
      description="My sample package",
      long_description="",
      author='TODO',
      author_email='todo@example.org',
      license='TODO',
      packages=['mousedb'],
      zip_safe=False,
      install_requires=[
          'Django',
          # 'Sphinx',
          # ^^^ Not sure if this is needed on readthedocs.org
          # 'something else?',
          ],
      )
```

After committing/pushing/whatever this file, you can go to your readthedocs settings for your project. Enable the "use virtualenv" setting. This will "nstall your project inside a virtualenv using setup.py install".

The end result is that everything python-related that readthedocs does will have your project in it's `sys.path`.

The probable cause of your problems is that you run sphinx from within your "root" directory on your local system, where python magically finds the `mousedb/` package in your current directory. But readthedocs apparently runs it from within the `Docs/` directory and thus cannot find `mousedb`.

Comment: I am looking for the "use virtualenv" setting for the `.readthedocs.yml` file but I can't find it. What is it called? https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html#python

Comment: I believe virtualenvs are now always used, and there is no setting for it anymore.